# fetch vote limit and showing all vote counts for a question in one fell swoop

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There appears to be a fetch vote limit of one per second.

Oftentimes I want to see all the votes for all responses to a question.  Would it be possible to get all vote counts for all responses to a question when you request the vote count for one response?  Alternatively, if you look at the vote count for a question, it should show the vote count for all responses to the question.

Comment: Is this a feature request for [API 2.0](http://stackapps.com/q/2588/8284)?

Comment: @Chris I guess I'm wondering if its possible to either remove the fetch vote limit or to show all vote counts when you request one vote count

Answer (score 8):

Why? Are you merely interested in seeing the vote splits without concern for the quality of the answer or do you actually spend time reading the answer and wondering what the splits are?

If it's the former, you probably just want to vote along with the hive mind and this feature should not be implemented.

If it's the latter, then you'll perhaps spend more than a second to glance at the answer, and hence won't run into the issues you face now. So again, there is no need for this feature.

Comment: Sometimes when reviewing a response, there are other responses with essentially the same content but different vote numbers.  In those circumstances, I wonder if someone downvoted every response or if someone just downvoted the one response.  I quickly want to see how the other responses were voted, and invariably that will involve seeing all of the vote counts